# Printing British Symbol £?

Tags: symbols

How does one print the '£' symbol?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431452/printing-british-symbol-in-latex?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 9):

`\pounds` is what you need.

Comment: Although, it doesn't work everywhere. For example MathOverflow is processed with MathJax and that doesn't seem to recognise either `\pounds` or `\textsterling`.

Answer (score 8):

I guess this should be `\pounds`, according to http://selinap.com/2008/07/latex-special-characters/

Answer (score 6):

There are very effective resources for finding symbols (not only math symbols), as suggested here: [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Answer (score 5):

If you use `inputenc` then you can just write `£`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
£ etc
\end{document}
```